# Using module bundlers and dynamic config firebase

Tags: firebase, webpack

I have an issue where I cannot use `init.js`, which I have done in the past when importing firebase through the reserved hosting urls.

`<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>`

This is the script that I am trying to use, and I am importing my firebase modules with:
`import * as firebase from "firebase/app";`

But I am trying to use webpack, with this. I have tried including `init.js` in my html, and my bundle as well, but without success.

Is there any way to use `init.js` with my module bundler?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party, but better late than never if somebody needs it :)

We wanted to do the same at [my company](https://divriots.com), for two reasons

1. not having to specify the firebase config ourself, as the `init.js` script contains it
2. automatic pickup of emulators when the `useEmulator=true` query param is specified (handy when you want to choose which emulators to start)

So we trick the script into doing what we want!

Basically the script looks for a global *firebase* variable which does not exist when using the modules. So we provide one for it to work.

Here's the code we use:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { connectFunctionsEmulator, getFunctions } from 'firebase/functions';

export async function initFirebase(): Promise<void> {
  // provide a fake firebase proxy object to the hosting init script
  // to get the boilerplate done (firebase conf + automatic connection
  // to started emulators)
  const proxy: any = {
    initializeApp: (c: any) => initializeApp(c),
  };
  // emulators done under development check to help with the tree-shaking
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    proxy.firestore = () => ({
      useEmulator: (h: any, p: any) =>
        connectFirestoreEmulator(getFirestore(), h, p),
    });
    proxy.functions = () => ({
      useEmulator: (h: any, p: any) =>
        connectFunctionsEmulator(getFunctions(), h, p),
    });
    proxy.auth = () => ({
      useEmulator: (h: any, p: any) => connectAuthEmulator(getAuth(), h, p),
    });
  }
  const _global = globalThis as any;
  _global.firebase = proxy;
  try {
    await import(`/__/firebase/init.js${
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '?useEmulator=true' : ''
      }`
    );
  } finally {
    delete _global.firebase;
  }
}
```

You'll notice I only setup the proxies for firestore/functions/auth as those are the only ones we emulate at the moment. If you don't care for the emulators, you can skip the entire code paths when *process.env.NODE* is 'development'.